# Django / How to evaluate a django variable inside a bracket expression?

Tags: django

In my html file I need to define a variable for a js file.

```
<script>
 var gltf_home = "{% static '/3d/ {{ scene.GltfFileToLoad }} ' %}";
</script>
```

which gives as an output :

*/static/3d/%7B%7B%20scene.GltfFileToLoad%20%7D%7D*

instead of

*/static/3d/00-world.glb*

And this alternative

```
var gltf_home = "{% static '/3d/' {{ scene.GltfFileToLoad }} %}";
```

gives

*/static/3d/*

What would be the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with the [**`|add`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add):

```
var gltf_home = "{% static '/3d/'|add:scene.GltfFileToLoad %}";
```

But I would advise *not* to do this: perform the logic in the view, and work with the [**`|json_script`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script), this will properly encode the data in a JSON blob, and thus prevents escaping, etc.

Comment: Thanks. it works. I will also investigate the json solution. Little mistake I made : GltfFileToLoad instead of scene.GltfFileToLoad